# How to avoid concurrent transactions affecting a single entity

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, weblogic, middleware

HELP! 
**the case** is when two or more transactions are trying to affect the same client monetary account in some external system. I need the second transaction be performed until the first one has finished. 

**consider:**

- there are two or more transactions trying to affect the same balance

- there are multiple clients at the same time

- working with 1000 TPS with 100ms avg per transaction

**ideas:**
- as we are working with multi threads to support 1000TPS i'm trying to create Queues based on the Client ID. using some kind of workmanager that limit one thread by Client. So if i have 2 request with the same clientID at same time dynamically can queue the second.

**tools**
i'm trying to use Oracle tools for example:

- Fusion Middleware: using the Workmanager based on message context [not sure if possible because looks like context can be based only on session data] i like WorkManager because has no performance issues

 - Oracle OCEP: creating a dynamic queue using the CQL [ not sure if possible and performance]

 - Oracle Advance Queuing: maybe possible with transactions group.

thanks for any idea

Comment: Is there some reason that the simplest approach-- using the database's inherent row-level lock mechanism-- is insufficient?  If there are a small enough number of monetary accounts such that there is a high probability that any two transactions would conflict, it may make sense to proactively distribute transactions among threads.  For a normal system, though, the odds of a conflict would be small enough that it wouldn't make sense to try to proactively schedule anything.

Comment: thanks Justin, the problem is performance we are working with 1K or 2K TPS and we need fast response. and maybe 5 millions of transactions and clients. the problem using Database in the solution to control the situations is time and create overhead establishing connections and upserts. based in some experiences i prefer to find a tool with out of the box capacity. but i'm open to any idea

Comment: I don't follow the comment about the "overhead establishing connections".  Presumably, you're going to have database connections regardless and those physical connections are going to be relatively persistent regardless of the solution you implement.  The database already provides out of the box, automatic locking to prevent concurrent modification of a single row.  What is it about the pattern of transactions in your system that makes you believe that it would be more sensible to check for row lock contention in advance rather than letting threads block there is actual contention?

Comment: you are right, connections are persistent the problem is that i need to establish many connections to the DB and generate more network traffic between DB and the application server. but that isn't a big issue. maybe what i'm trying to do is don't merge my business solution logic with the multithread contention. separate core business logic with the behavior. maybe avoid coding if for example oracle weblogic already has a solution, so i don't have to invest time developing some specific solution. right now i'm using Oracle OSB

Comment: The number of connections to the database and the amount of network traffic is independent of whatever solution you implement.  The back end database has already built very robust row-level locking that ensures that two threads cannot modify the same row at the same time and to allow other threads to queue up until the first thread's transaction completes.  From a performance standpoint, it would only make sense to do something on the front-end to schedule transactions to avoid back-end contention if you expected to save more time by avoiding back-end contention than you spent scheduling.

Comment: With normal workloads against "client monetary accounts", there isn't going to be enough back-end contention to offset the cost of trying to schedule things in advance-- most systems are going to be doing transactions against many different accounts, not thousands of transactions against the same account every second.  If your system has a different pattern of transactions that makes it worthwhile to schedule things in advance, it would be helpful to understand that pattern in order to be able to help you devise a solution.

Comment: @JustinCave is dead on. Your Oracle EE DB will take 1-2K T/s with a smile on its face (if your hardware can take it) and maintain ACID principals while doing it. Don't reinvent this wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your problem.

In you question you asked, wether it is possible to perform a second transaction on a row before the first is completed. This is impossible! A database which follows the A**C**ID paradigm has to be **C**onsistent! So you can't "overtake" the first transaction!!! If you want to do that, you should use NoSQL Databases (like MongoDB, ...) where consistency is not that strong.

But maybe you want to know, if there is a Oracle view to figure out, wether a row is locked or not? Let's assume, that there is a view like that. You would check this view and if there is no lock, you start your update/delete. But you can't be sure that this will work because even 1ms after you checked it, another process can put a lock on it.

The only thing you can do is, to put a "select ... for update **NOWAIT**" before you UPDATE/DELETE statement. 
If the row is locked, you will get a exception (ORA-00054: Resource busy). This is the recommended/"out of the box way" to let the database manage row-level-locking for you!

See the following example with the emp table. Consider: to check this out, start this code in two different sessions at the same time.

```
declare
  l_sal number;
  resource_busy exception;                    -- declare your own exception
  pragma exception_init (resource_busy, -54); -- connect your exception with ORA-00054

begin
   select sal
     into l_sal 
     from emp 
     where empno = 7934
   for update NOWAIT;

   update emp
   set sal = sal + 100
   where empno = 7934;

   exception
     when resource_busy then
       null;  -- in your case, simply do nothing, if the row is locked

end;
```